# Rust compiler unable to infer enough information about generic types

Tags: generics, rust

I am learning Rust and came across something similar to this

```
struct A<T> {
    some_vec: Vec<T>,
    pub secret: &'static str
}

struct B{}

struct C{}

impl B {
    fn foo<T>(&self) {

        let bar: A<T> = A { 
            some_vec: Vec::new(), 
            secret: "123" 
        };

        println!("The secret is {}", bar.secret);
    }
}

impl C {
    fn foo<T>(&self) {
        let b = B{};
        b.foo();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c = C{};
    c.foo();
}
```

This produces the compiler error

```
error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required [--explain E0282]
  --> src/main.rs:26:11
   |>
26 |>         b.foo();
   |>           ^^^
```

I have seen posts about the same error message but I was unable to figure out the solution in this case. What information (related to `b.foo()`) am I missing to specify?

Comment: You have to call `b.foo::<i32>()` and `c.foo::<i32>()` (or any other type instead of `i32`). You actually never specified this type parameter... Too lazy to make an answer out of this right now... sorry :P

Comment: Thanks for the missing piece! If someone makes a real answer out of this, I'll mark it as solved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since type inference is a novelty to many coming to Rust, let's explain it a bit more in depth.

In essence, type inference is a bit like those "maze" games you may have played in magazines:

[image]

You have a bunch of places where the type is unknown on the left hand, to connect to a handful of known types on the right hand. How to? Well, by examining the relationships between types!

The simplest relationship (beyond no need to guess) is a 1-degree relationship:

```
let x: String = "Hello, World".into();
```

In Rust, we know that `into()` comes from the `Into<T>` trait that is implemented by `&str`, but which `T`? Well, `into()` returns a `T` and the type of the expression is expected to be a `String`, therefore it *must* be `Into<String>`.

In order to solve type inference, the compiler will therefore build some kind of graph of relationships between the places where the type need be inferred and the known types (in Rust, the function signature must be explicit, so it should not have to search too far), and then will try to deduce the types little by little.

---

Let's examine the current use case:

```
fn main() {
    let c = C{};
    c.foo();
}
```

Here, `c.foo();` calls `C::foo<T>()`: we need to deduce `T`. What information do we have? None. Zilch. Nada.

In this case, unable to solve the problem, the compiler bails out and asks you (the developer) what you wanted `T` to be. You can specify it in multiple ways:

- the general method is making use of the so-called "turbofish" operator `::<>` as in `c.foo::<i32>()`
- in the specific case where the result cannot be deduced, you can simply ascribe a type to the left-hand variable as in `let x: i32 = ...;`
- it should be noted that often times you need not supply a *complete* type, and can make use of the `_` character to elide part of it as in `let x: Vec<_> = ...;` or `c.foo::<Vec<_>>()` if the compiler has enough information to deduce `_` on its own of course.

Answer (score 3):

Often, generic functions will use their type parameters in the type of their parameters. In that case, the compiler can infer the type parameters from the type of the arguments on a call.

However, in your case, `B::foo` and `C::foo` don't have any parameters using `T`. Therefore, each call needs to specify a concrete type for `T` explicitly. This is done by adding `::<X>` (where `X` is a type) after the name of the function, before the parentheses.

In `C::foo`, presumably, you'll want to forward `C::foo`'s `T` to `B::foo`, so you'd write:

```
impl C {
    fn foo<T>(&self) {
        let b = B {};
        b.foo::<T>();
    }
}
```

Then in `main`, you can use any type you want:

```
fn main() {
    let c = C {};
    c.foo::<i32>();
}
```